# ActiveMQ 5.16.3 Windows and Hawtio Login Problems

Tags: java, windows, activemq-classic, hawtio, jolokia

I've installed Apache ActiveMQ 5.16.3 on my windows 10 laptop for testing purposes
And i downloaded hawtio 2.13.3 as a webapp for monitoring.

Steps i did to install and configure :

1. Downloaded ActiveMQ and extracted it to a folder
2. Downloaded Hawtio and extracted it at ActiveMQ webapps folder
3. Added Hawtio as a resource under jetty.xml file
4. Added -dhawtio configurations under activemq file at bin folder
5. Ran ActiveMQ service installer "InstallService.bat"
6. Ran ActiveMQ Service and navigated to 127.0.0.1/admin
7. ActiveMQ works , i now navigate to 127.0.0.1/hawtio
8. I attempted logging in using the default user and password (admin,admin)
9. I received an error stating my credentials are invalid

After attempting to login to hawtio web i notice this error in my activemq batch file

```
INFO  | qtp1675905101-41 | Hawtio login is using 1800 sec. HttpSession timeout
WARN  | qtp1675905101-41 | Login failed due to: No LoginModules configured for karaf
```

Did i miss something on the way?

Thanks,

Comment: You might consider moving to [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/), ActiveMQ's next-generation message broker. It ships with a web console based on Hawtio 2 so there's no need to configure all of this manually.

Comment: Hey @JustinBertram , thanks for the reply , currently the infrastructure i maintain is apache activemq based and therefore i asked for help regarding hawtio here , i will remember your opinion for future reference !

Comment: It's worth noting that ActiveMQ Artemis supports all the same protocols as ActiveMQ Classic so none of your clients should need to be updated unless perhaps they are using some kind of non-JMS ActiveMQ-specific features.

Answer (score 1):

Okay,

For anyone else facing this weird problem , i solved the issue by myself after 3 days of searching for an answer.

Since ActiveMQ Is ran by a batch file from the /bin folder (C:\Active_MQ_Windows\apache-activemq-5.16.3\bin , to be more percise)

by activemq.bat , we need to add the following lines to the batch file.

The following lines are :

```
 if "%ACTIVEMQ_OPTS%" == "" set ACTIVEMQ_OPTS=-Xms1G -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config="%ACTIVEMQ_CONF%\login.config"
```

Change to :

```
if "%ACTIVEMQ_OPTS%" == "" set ACTIVEMQ_OPTS=-Xms1G -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config="%ACTIVEMQ_CONF%\login.config" -Dhawtio.realm=activemq -Dhawtio.role=admins -Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=org.apache.activemq.jaas.GroupPrincipal
```

There is an "activemq" file in the bin folder (as a reference for env file in linux)
Do not edit any of its contents , everything is managed by the batch file.

**EDIT**

The above solution is for manually debugging with activemq.bat

To apply hawtio at activemq service level , add the following lines
to the wrapper.conf following your os type (win32 or win64)

Lines:

```
wrapper.java.additional.13=-Dhawtio.realm=activemq
wrapper.java.additional.14=-Dhawtio.role=admins
wrapper.java.additional.15=-Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=org.apache.activemq.jaas.GroupPrincipal
```

Add additional accordingly (if you have more than 13 lines change the additional to 14 etc..)

```
# Java Additional Parameters
# note that n is the parameter number starting from 1.
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Dactivemq.home="%ACTIVEMQ_HOME%"
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Dactivemq.base="%ACTIVEMQ_BASE%"
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
wrapper.java.additional.5=-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="%ACTIVEMQ_CONF%/broker.ks"
wrapper.java.additional.6=-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="%ACTIVEMQ_CONF%/broker.ts"
wrapper.java.additional.7=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
wrapper.java.additional.8=-Dorg.apache.activemq.UseDedicatedTaskRunner=true
wrapper.java.additional.9=-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties
wrapper.java.additional.10=-Dactivemq.conf="%ACTIVEMQ_CONF%"
wrapper.java.additional.11=-Dactivemq.data="%ACTIVEMQ_DATA%"
wrapper.java.additional.12=-Djava.security.auth.login.config="%ACTIVEMQ_CONF%/login.config"
wrapper.java.additional.13=-Dhawtio.realm=activemq
wrapper.java.additional.14=-Dhawtio.role=admins
wrapper.java.additional.15=-Dhawtio.rolePrincipalClasses=org.apache.activemq.jaas.GroupPrincipal
```

Since this isn't documented ANYWHERE (Amq Website or Hawtio Website) I hope
this answer will help with future issues.